# TypeError: when calling User.objects.create()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am able to get a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`.

> TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new_password'

It would be great if anybody could figure me out where i'm doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

serializers.py :

```
class PasswordChangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, max_length=30)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, max_length=30)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['old_password', 'new_password', 'confirm_password']


    def validate(self, data):
        old_password = data['old_password']
        new_password = data['new_password']
        confirm_password = data['confirm_password']

        user_queryset = User.objects.all()

        if user_queryset.exists() and user_queryset.count() == 1:
            user_set = user_queryset.first()

            if not user_set.check_password(old_password):
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'old_password': 'Wrong password!'})

            if confirm_password != new_password:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password must be confirmed correctly!'})

        return data

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.set_password(validated_data['new_password'])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py :

```
class PasswordChangeAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = PasswordChangeSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        password_ser = PasswordChangeSerializer(data=data)
        if password_ser.is_valid():
            password_ser.save()
            new_data = password_ser.data
            return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({"msg":"invalid user!"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: can you validate if the problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this code. It will create a new user every time because there is no way for the serializer to fetch the right instance.

I would suggest reading more carefully how edit records with DRF.
Read this [How to update a model record in Django-Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014890/how-to-update-a-model-record-in-django-rest) answer to add custom actions to your viewset.

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the user using email or pk (a simple get should work IMO).

> `user = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)`

Once you have the `user` object, use the serializer the following way.

> `password_ser = PasswordChangeSerializer(user, data=data)`

This way the serializer knows which user object it is trying to update.

Without the user object the serializer assumes that incoming data is going to be used for creation of a new object and it cannot find the `new_password` property in your default `User` model. Hence the error.